# MapReduce on several columns

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to **MapReduce** and have troubles with writing a MapReduce job which would work with several columns at once for a CSV file.

I would like to find for each garment group the most frequent product, the second most frequent section and the most frequent department so that the output would look according to the following schema: **garment_group**, **product**, **section**,  **department**. This is based on the **articles.csv** dataset from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/odins0n/hm512x512).

So far I could only find for each garment group the most frequent product and do not understand how to incorporate the other columns. This is my code:

```
from mrjob.step import MRStep
from mrjob.util import log_to_stream, log_to_null
from mr3px.csvprotocol import CsvProtocol
import csv 
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MyMRJob1(MRJob):
    
    
    OUTPUT_PROTOCOL = CsvProtocol  # write output as CSV
    
    def set_up_logging(cls, quiet=False, verbose=False, stream=None):  
        log_to_stream(name='mrjob', debug=verbose, stream=stream)
        log_to_stream(name='__main__', debug=verbose, stream=stream)
        
    def mapper(self, _, line):
        result = next(csv.reader([line],quotechar=None)) # extract columns from line

        garment_group_name = result[23]
        prod_name = result[2]
        #section_name = result[21]
        #department_name = result[15]
       # name = result[2]
        

        #skip sparse entries and header
        if prod_name == "prod_name" or prod_name == "" or garment_group_name == "": #skip sparse entries and header
            return
        yield (garment_group_name,prod_name), 1
       
        
    def reducer(self,garmetProd,valuelist):
        garmet, prod = garmetProd
        output = sum(valuelist)
        yield None,(garmet,prod,output)
        
    def mapper_top(self, _, line):
        result = line # input from last round already a list of strings
        
        garmet = result[0]
        prod = result[1]
        nProd = result[2]

        yield garmet, (prod,nProd)
        
            
    def reducer_top(self,garmet,values):
        mostProduct = "" # most favourite product per garmet group
        maxBought = 0 # max amount of times bought

        for (prod,nProds) in values:
            if int(nProds) >  maxBought:
                maxBought = int(nProds)
                mostProduct = prod

        if  maxBought > 0: 
            #CsvProtocol needs None key for output
            yield None, (garmet,mostProduct)       
               

    def steps(self):
         return [
            MRStep(mapper  = self.mapper, 
                   reducer = self.reducer),
            MRStep(mapper   = self.mapper_top,
                   reducer  = self.reducer_top)
        ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMRJob1.run()
```

Comment: Do you have to use MapReduce? It's really quite dated now and there's no reason to use it other than for educational purposes. You'll find Apache Spark much easier to use.

Comment: yes, unfortunately, I have to make it only with MapReduce. But good to hear that this is not widely used anymore because it is really a lot of work.
I would appreciate any hint on how to organize the logic of this task

Comment: Historically people would use Hive here (which still runs MapReduce underneath), then you can just write SQL queries over your data. Given your fairly complex output requirements then you'd need to write several MR jobs otherwise.